# In `irb`, backticks throw an exception, but in `rails c`, they don't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, backticks

- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 8
- Ruby version: 2.4.1
- Rails version: 5.1.4

I just used `rails new` to create a brand new Rails project.  In its directory, with `irb`, I tried to execute a shell command for an executable that did not exist, and an exception was thrown:

```
irb(main):001:0> `foobar`
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - foobar
    from (irb):1:in ``'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:335:in `exec'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
    from /home/jackson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

Yet when I try to do the same thing in my Rails environment with `rails c`, an exception is not thrown.  The backticks return `nil` instead:

```
irb(main):001:0> `foobar`
rails_console: No such file or directory - foobar
=> nil
```

This inconsistency seems to be reflected beyond the Rails console.  Backticks also return `nil` in my Rails application.  This is an issue because error handling for missing commands in one of our gems is broken because it doesn't thrown an exception: https://github.com/dstil/localtunnel/blob/87b1e4b98f600c2a767654caf0a2d94fef5be0e5/lib/localtunnel/client.rb#L37-L41

Is this difference in behavior intentional?  If not, what's wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that Rails [overrides backticks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.4/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb) in an attempt to standardize behavior:

```
class Object
  # Makes backticks behave (somewhat more) similarly on all platforms.
  # On win32 `nonexistent_command` raises Errno::ENOENT; on Unix, the
  # spawned shell prints a message to stderr and sets $?. We emulate
  # Unix on the former but not the latter.
  def `(command) #:nodoc:
    super
  rescue Errno::ENOENT => e
    STDERR.puts "#$0: #{e}"
  end
end
```

There's blame to go around:

- Rails for replacing a core method.
- The gem for using backticks rather than something safer and cleaner such as `Open3`.
- Ruby for not specifying how `` Kernel#` `` is supposed to behave (and possibly even having backticks if you're opinionated enough).

There are ways around this. You could try to remove the ActiveSupport override in an initializer:

```
Object.send(:remove_method, :'`')
```

so that the standard backticks from `Kernel` will be used. Or if you never expect to have an `lt` command you could replace the gem's method:

```
module LocalTunnel
  class Client
    def self.package_installed?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Or maybe replace `LocalTunnel::Client.package_installed?` with your own implementation that works around the Rails override by checking the various ways that backticks can fail or uses the methods in `Open3` instead of backticks. You could also manually look for `lv` yourself by breaking up the `PATH` environment variable (using `File::PATH_SEPARATOR`) and `File.executable?`.

Which kludge you use depends on what portability requirements you have and what works in your environments.

Comment: It sounds to me like I should just throw backticks into the garbage from here on out.  Do you have a suggestion on how I might generally replace backticks with "something safer and cleaner such as `Open3`", preferably with a synchronous code example?

Comment: I tend to stay away from backticks, the one argument version of `system`, and anything else that will invoke a shell, far too fragile and error prone to use properly. Instead of `%x{some_command -arg}` you'd probably use `Open3.capture2('some_command', '-arg')` instead (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2).